# Is installed package can be move to SDCard

Tags: java, android, debugging, package, sd-card

I got a list of installed packages, how can I find out which one can be move to sdcard?

```
List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

}
```

---

```
    if (_pm != null) {
        List<PackageInfo> list = _pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo current  = list.get(i);
            long pkgSize = new File(current.applicationInfo.sourceDir).length();
            String pkgName = current.packageName;
            String appName = current.applicationInfo.loadLabel(_pm).toString();
            Drawable appIcon = current.applicationInfo.loadIcon(_pm);

            //if (pInfo.installLocation != PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY)//?

            PackageItem pi = new PackageItem(pkgName, pkgSize, appIcon, appName);

            if (_locationMode == LOCATION_PHONE) {
                if (!onSdCard(pkgName)) {
                    _adapter.add(pi);
                }
            } else {
                if (onSdCard(pkgName)) {
                    _adapter.add(pi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can neither find .installLocation from my current, nor find .INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY from PackageInfo. What 's the problem?

---

I can neither find .installLocation from my current, nor find .INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY from PackageInfo. What 's the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `0` instead of an actual, [constant flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_ACTIVITIES) (i.e. `PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES`).

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is I can't find packaheInfo.installLocation in my eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.java#PackageInfo.0installLocation) knows all,

```
List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

for (PackageInfo pInfo : list) {        
    if (pInfo.installLocation != PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY) {
        // then it can be moved to the SD card
    } else {
        // otherwise, it can only be installed on internal storage
    }
}
```

Comment: I can neither find .installLocation from my current, nor find .INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY from PackageInfo. What 's the problem?

Comment: Should parse location from manifest.xml. @see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065219/accessing-androidinstalllocation-manifest-attribute