# How we can programmatically detect application name which is able to move into SD card(External storage)?

Tags: android

I want to detect application name which is able to move into SD card or external storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966158/844882). Also, refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942749/is-installed-package-can-be-move-to-sdcard/10966158#comment14421506_10966158) for information on how to access the `installLocation` variable in the `PackageInfo` class.